# Meteor service-configuration package collection

Tags: meteor

When we execute the following code where does configuration get stored. In other words what is the collection name where configuration gets stored.

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
    { service: "weibo" },
    {
        $set: {
            clientId: "1292962797",
            loginStyle: "popup",
            secret: "75a730b58f5691de5522789070c319bc"
        }
    }
);
```

Is there a way to change to name of collection where Service Configurations are stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the collection is :

```
"meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration"
```

You can get this name using :

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations._name
```

Comment: Is it possible to change default name `meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration` to any other name say `config1`

Comment: @PavanKumar, did you ever find out how?

Comment: @OliverKane No. It seems there isn't api to change the name of collection.

Answer (score 1):

It's been ages, but if someone needs it, following is the way:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations = new Mongo.Collection(
    'custom_name', {
        _preventAutopublish: true,
        connection: Meteor.isClient ? Accounts.connection : Meteor.connection,
    }
);
```

It should be one of the first codes executed (probably top of your server/index file).

Source: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/service-configuration/service_configuration_common.js